# Bridging my VM with an OpenVPN adapter

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vpn, vmware, openvpn

Beginner user here,I start to slowly learn about networks, virtual machines and so.

Here is my set up.

I have a host system, running Windows 8.1. On my host system is installed OpenVPN, with a connection configured to my server. 
I am perfectly able to use the VPN, access the server on the ip 10.10.0.1

On my host system is installed VMWare Workstation (v10 iirc). I created a Windows 7 virtual machine.

Simply put, I want all network traffic coming out of my virtual machine sent to my VPN. After some research, it seems that I have to configure my VM to use a bridge connection.

Here are my current settings on VMWare :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVzAm.jpg

The VM is configured to use a bridge connection, and in the Virtual Network Editor I edited the VMNet0 connection to use only my VPN adapter (TAP-Windows Adapter V9 #2)

However (as you can guess) I don't have any access within the guest network (Windows 7)

One of my friend (sadly on linux) suggested me to put the VM on an host-only adapter, and create a routing table which redirect all traffic on this host-only adapter to my VPN adapter. However I have no idea on how to do that.

If you have any idea, feel free to help me :)

Thanks !

Comment: Did you ever get this working ? I do not believe it is very difficult to do ..